# I want add Textboxs in windows form application in user specified number

Tags: c#, .net, c#-5.0

I want add Textboxs in windows form application in user specified number  and insert values in the  database also..plz  help me  friends

Comment: I'm genuinely curious what sort of answer you are actually expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add dynamic TextBoxes in windows forms

```
TextBox[] txtBoxes = new TextBox[userValue];
for (int i = 0; i < txtBoxes.Length; i++) 
{
  var txt = new TextBox();
  txtBoxes[i] = txt;
}
```

This will initialize the textboxes. Later you can use them to get the input.

Inserting in databases is not a single line answer. At least not before you learn how to work with databases.

So its better you go through this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxt2cwcc.aspx)

Comment: Maybe you could summarize here so if the link dies the information survives?

Comment: how to insert records  of that text boxes to database

Comment: it is possible to add dynamic insert query to textbox

Comment: Could you be more clear with what you exactly want ?